# How to find a value in a vector and return its index, in a functional way?

Tags: rust, iterator

I can't find in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partial_cmp) an iterator method that will allow to write code equivalent to this:

```
let v = vec![1,2,3];
let key_of_two = v.iter().find_key(|x| x == 2);
assert_eq!(key_of_two, 1)
```

There's only `find` method, but how to return the index, instead of the element?

Comment: Try `Iterator::position`.

Comment: @edwardw Oh my god. So this is how it's called. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately there is `Iterator::position`:

```rust
let v = vec![1,2,3];
let key_of_two = v.iter().position(|&x| x == 2);
assert_eq!(key_of_two, Some(1));
```